# Subtraction of dates returning 0 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created the following function:

```
create or replace function tempo_medio_atendimento_dia return number is
  counter number; 
  last_date date;
  date_diff number;
  type_info varchar(100);
  cursor c1 is select e.data_pedido from encomenda e, funcionario f where e.funcionario.codigo = f.codigo and to_char(e.data_pedido, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2015-04-23' order by e.data_pedido;
  begin
    counter := 0.0;    
    for c1_x in c1 loop
      last_date := to_date(c1_x.data_pedido);
      select dump(last_date) into type_info from dual;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TYPE INFO: ' || type_info);
      if c1%rowcount > 1 then 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DATE:' || c1_x.data_pedido || ' - ' || last_date || ' = ' || (to_date(c1_x.data_pedido) - to_date(last_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60);
        select (to_date(c1_x.data_pedido) - to_date(last_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 into date_diff from dual;
        counter := counter + date_diff;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return counter;
end tempo_medio_atendimento_dia;
```

The dates are printing correctly and I've checked the `c1_x.data_pedido` type and it's `12` (DATE), but for some reason when I try to subtract the dates, it returns 0.

```
select (to_date(c1_x.data_pedido) - to_date(last_date)) * 24 * 60 * 60 into date_diff from dual;
```

However, if I run the following code directly, it returns 360, as it's supposed.

```
select (to_date('23/04/2015 10:49:12') - to_date('23/04/2015 10:43:12')) * 24 * 60 * 60 from dual;
```

As the data type seems to be correct in the function, I can't understand why the subtraction isn't working. Any tip?

Comment: The first thing you do in your loop is set `last_date` equal to the value of `c1_x.data_pedido`. Anything minus itself is 0. In addition to that, I would suggest not trying to cast a date as a date. I don't know the data type of `data_pedido`, but `last_date` is definitely already a date.

Comment: @HepC Oh no...I can't believe I lost so much time on this newbie thing! And I know I shouldn't do that, but that was the desperation talking higher. Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: `to_date(last_date)` is useless. You are converting a `date` to a `varchar` just to convert it back to a `date` and all that using implicit data type conversion. If `data_pedido` is also a `date` then using `to_date()` on a `date` column to also convert it into a `varchar` and back into a `date` is just as senseless. Why do people always think they need to convert a `date` to a `date` using `to_date()`

Comment: Yes, I got it! Already fixed both things and it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you do in your loop is

```
last_date := to_date(c1_x.data_pedido);
```

That means later when you do the following

```
to_date(c1_x.data_pedido) - to_date(last_date)
```

You are subtracting `c1_x.data_pedido - c1_x.data_pedido`.

In addition to that, I would suggest not trying to cast a date as a date. I don't know the data type of data_pedido, but last_date is definitely already a date, so the call to `TO_DATE` is unnecessary.